# Get network information through Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, networking, command-line, wifi

Is there a command where, when entered outputs information such as:

- If the network connection is wired or wireless
- if it is a wireless network, the name of the wireless network
- How strong the signal is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type in terminal 'iw' and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you will see something like 
`iw
iw  iwconfig  iwevent   iwgetid   iwlist    iwpriv    iwspy`
all those are related to wireless internet, try `iwconfig` to show  statistic about signal and network interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a shell script for the first question:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if ! /bin/ip route | grep -q ^default; then
  echo "No Internet connection"
  echo
  exit 0
fi
if="$(/bin/ip route | 
  awk '$1 == "default" {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "dev") { i++;print $i; exit}}')"
if [ -z "$if" -o \! -e /sys/class/net/"$if" ]; then
  echo "Sorry, some error, aborting."
  echo
  exit 1
fi
if /usr/sbin/iw dev "$if" info &>/dev/null; then
  echo "The Internet connection is wireless."
  echo
  # uncomment the next line to start iwconfig
  # iwconfig
else
  echo "The Internet connection is wired."
  echo
fi
```

You can save this as e.g. ~/scripts/gatewayinfo.sh, make it executable via `chmod a+x ~/scripts/gatewayinfo.sh` and easily call it by making an alias definition (in e.g. `~/.alias`): `alias inetinfo="~/scripts/gatewayinfo.sh"`

Comment: The above script as a `wget`table pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JYB3GRFE

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running the script: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' I don't know much about shell scripting syntax, but if I remove it the script then says unexpected end of script (which I expected). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @TheRyan722 No idea. Maybe some copying error? The MD5 hash for the file (with trailing newline) should be: c65bfba31903b4caaadf6adf1da6284b If that is the same for you: What is the output of `bash -vx ./testscript.sh`?

Comment: The exact same thing as the script. Also getting errors about $'\r' not being a valid command.

Comment: You can use `ip route show default` so you don't need the parsing parts in your script. Output: `default via 192.168.1.1 dev phy0 proto static`.